# SQLite создается, но данные не записываются

Tags: java, android

Делаю так:

```
...
 // создаю объект для создания и управления версиями БД
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
   ....
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    // подключаюсь к БД
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    cv.put("date", "01.01.2001");
    cv.put("time", "18:18:00");
    // вставляем запись и получаю ее ID
    long rowID = db.insert("mytable", null, cv);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row inserted, ID = " + rowID);

 class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        // конструктор суперкласса
        super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "‐‐‐ onCreate database ‐‐‐");
        // создаем таблицу с полями
        db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
                + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + "date text,"
                + "time text" + ");");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
```

Создается таблица с полями, но они пустые. В чем может быть причина?

Лог следующий: row inserted, ID = -1

Comment: Для получения логов используйте метод `db.setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled(true);`, а после, с логами разберёмся

Comment: Либо используйте метод `db.insetrOrThrow()` внутри `try` `catch` блока заместо `db.insert()` и ловите `SQLException`

Comment: А че то не удается вызвать эти методы. Ругается что их нет.

Comment: Можно конкретнее, что написано в ошибке?

Comment: меня смущает этот кусок кода в месте где создается БД "time text" + ");"); здесь точно + нужен? ))

Comment: @ZigZag разницы между `"time text" + ");");`, `"time text);");` и `"t" + "i" + "m" + "e" + " " + "t" + "e" + "x" + "t" + ")" + ";");` нет абсолютно никакой

Comment: да, но зачем усложнять..

Comment: можно разнести саму операцию вставки в БД и получение ID, тоже разницы никакой, но иногда это создает проблемы..

Comment: @ZigZag это сделано, вероятно, для дальнейшего удобного копипаста и отделения названия колонок от синтаксических символов запроса. В любом случае данный код становится более читабельным.

Comment: Попробуйте задать `id`, как `_id` - Android иногда требует, что первичный ключ был задан с лидирующим подчеркиванием

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первую очередь необходимо понять причину ошибки - для этого нам нужны её логи.

Замените строку

```
long rowID = db.insert("mytable", null, cv);
```

на

```
try{
    long rowID = db.insertOrThrow("mytable", null, cv);
}catch(SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

и смотрите логи ошибки.

Comment: E/SQLiteLog: (1) table mytable has no column named time
W/System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table mytable has no column named time (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO mytable(time,date) VALUES (?,?)

Comment: Все заработало после того как я почистил кэш и удалил приложение. Всем спасибо за помощь.